# Set a file to never be merged, and always stay different for each branch

Tags: git

I have a project with multiple submodules all tracking specific branches. I want to make it so that the submodules will track a different branch depending on the checked out branch of the parent repo. So for example, if I switch the main repo to the staging branch, all the submodules should checkout to their staging branches as well. I have this mostly working by just changing the `.gitmodules` file accordingly on each branch so that each submodule tracks the branch I need it to. Now I can just checkout the parent repo to the branch I want and use `git submodules update --remote` to update the submodules.

My problem is that when I merge branches, I don't want the `.gitmodules` file to be overwritten and break this system I've made. I need this file to always stay different across branches, while still allowing git to track it. Is it possible to make git still track the `.gitmodules` file while only excluding it from merges?

Comment: Merges happen on commits. Not files. A commit is a snapshot of the _enitre repo_.

Comment: @evolutionxbox So then for instance, if I have a development branch and a production branch, and each branch has differences in their `.gitmodules` file. Wouldn't merging development into production overwrite the production branch's `.gitmodules` with the development one? I don't want that to happen, they need to stay different.

Comment: If you need them both to always be different, then you probably don't want to use git as a means of deployment or dependency management.

Comment: @evolutionxbox It's just that this application consists of several subprojects. The main project just contains the docker config, the scripts needed to start the application, and the submodules which are the actual application files. I was hoping Git would have a built-in way that I can keep all the submodules synced up to the same branch as the main repo, but it's looking like I'll just have to write custom scripts to manage that.

Comment: It's not possible in general today. You can set up a merge driver for `.gitmodules` that ignores one of the two branch tips, but Git will only *use* your merge driver if all three inputs (merge base file and both branch tip files) differ.

Comment: Git is for version control, not for project dependency management. For the sake of your project and your sanity I would ask you to look elsewhere. See continuous integration.